# Stop/freeze timer (setInterval) by button click or stop, when time ran out

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

Using `setInterval`, I made a timer which has countdown of 5 minutes. It is actived by button-click. When it reaches 0 minutes and 0 seconds, timer will be automatically stopped and performed some other actions.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
  function runTimer(){
     const CLOCK = setInterval(function () {
        let minute = 4;
        let sec = 59
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = (sec < 10) ? '0' + minute + ":" + '0' + sec
            : '0' + minute + ":" + sec;
        if (sec != -1) {
            sec--;
        }
        // if time  0 minutes 0 seconds, stop timer 
        if (minute == 0 && sec == -1) {
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = '00:00';
            stopTimer(CLOCK);
        }
        if (sec == -1) {
            sec = 59;
            if (minute != 0) {
                minute--;
            } else {
                sec = -1;
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
  }
 function stopTimer(CLOCK) 
    {
      clearInterval(CLOCK);
      // GO RIGHT;
    }
 document.getElementById('start-test').addEventListener("click", runTimer);
});
```

Timer runs out and actions performed. Here is everything ok.
But I can't find a way to stop/freeze timer by button click.
I need something like (I know it is wrong, but as an example):

```
 function testDone(ClOCK)
 {
   clearInterval(CLOCK);
   // GO LEFT;
 }

 <button id="send_quiz" onclick="testDone(CLOCK)" type="submit">Done!</button>
```

or

```
 document.getElementById('send_quiz').addEventListener("click", testDone);
```

Neither idea is functional.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You need to set the `CLOCK` reference within scope of all functions. Then `clearInterval(CLOCK)` will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `CLOCK` variable to an outer scope where it can be accessed by all the functions.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
  let CLOCK;
  function runTimer(){
     CLOCK = setInterval(function () {
        let minute = 4;
        let sec = 59
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = (sec < 10) ? '0' + minute + ":" + '0' + sec
            : '0' + minute + ":" + sec;
        if (sec != -1) {
            sec--;
        }
        // if time  0 minutes 0 seconds, stop timer 
        if (minute == 0 && sec == -1) {
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = '00:00';
            stopTimer(CLOCK);
        }
        if (sec == -1) {
            sec = 59;
            if (minute != 0) {
                minute--;
            } else {
                sec = -1;
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
  }
 function stopTimer(CLOCK) 
    {
      clearInterval(CLOCK);
      // GO RIGHT;
    }
 document.getElementById('start-test').addEventListener("click", runTimer);
 document.getElementById('send_quiz').addEventListener("click", testDone);
function testDone()
 {
   clearInterval(CLOCK);
   // GO LEFT;
 }
});
```

Comment: thank you, that worked, but for educational purposes, I wanted to know whether there is a chance to do it with `const`. Or it is not important to use it here?

Comment: @A.Volg Variables declared with `const` must be initialized immediately, so I do not think it can be done. `CLOCK` cannot be accessed outside of the function anyway, so it is not that important.

Answer (score 1):

Simply declare your minute and sec variable from outside of the function.  When you click the  start button, your function will get the value from outside of the function.

That means javascript never hold values when the function ends, thats it...